# How do I express Cartesian product for $X^{n}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know there are some answers for this question, however, I have failed to find anything to give hints on how to express it with a real set.

For instance, if there is a set $$X=\{0,1\}$$
How do I express the Cartesian Products of $X^{n}$?

I know $X \times X = \{0,0\}\{0,1\}\{1,0\}\{1,1\}$ but I have no clue how to do $X^{n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$X^n = \{(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \mid x_i\in X, 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n\}$$ or more generally $$X_1 \times \cdots \times X_n = \{(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \mid x_i \in X_i, 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n\}.$$

Comment: How might you write this more formally without the '$\cdots$' notation?

Comment: @DanChristensen What about $(x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ or $(x_i: 1 \leq i \leq n)$ and similar variants?

Comment: @amrsa Isn't this just substituting one informal notation for another?
 Maybe something to do with the set of all unary functions mapping the natural numbers $\leq n$ to the set $X$?

Comment: @DanChristensen Of course you are right, but I just meant a way of not using the dots, as someone might ask what's going on in that gap? Now if every time you deal with these objects you use the more formal notation you proposed (and with which I agree) it becomes difficult to read. Actually, I think that most mathematicians never use other notation than the dots one. But this might depend on the area of mathematics...

Comment: @amrsa I am interested, as an amateur, in formal proofs. The only way I can think of to formally define the notion of $X^n$ for arbitrary $n$ is the set of all functions mapping the first $n$ natural numbers to the set $X$. Yes, I'm splitting hairs, but that's what you do in formal proofs. An ordered triple of real numbers, for example, can be thought of as a function mapping $\{1,2,3\}$ to $R$.

Answer (score 0):

So $X^n$ is the ordered $n$-tuples of elements of $X$. So in your example, $(0,1,0,0)\in X^4$. The fact that they are ordered is important, so while $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ are both in $X^2$, they are not equal. We typically use the notation with parentheses rather than brackets, since brackets are more frequently used for sets, where the order elements are written does not matter.

As another example, if $\mathbb{R}$ is the real numbers, we typically identify the points on an $xy$-plane with $\mathbb{R}^2$, where the $x$-coordinate is the first ordered element, and the $y$-coordinate is the second. We identify three dimensional space with $\mathbb{R}^3$ in a similar way.